# AFnetworking synchronise in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've created a class Server Manager to handle all server communication stuff which includes **AFnetworking** files.

The instance is alloced in this way, and it is able to operate GET or POST request.

```
+ (ServerManager*) instance
{
    static ServerManager *Instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Instance = [[ServerManager alloc]init];
    });
    return Instance;
}
```

But my question is, when I want to get the response from the server outside the class? How can I implement that in the synchronized way?

For example,in the view controller I've:

```
 ServerManager *serverManager = [ServerManager instance];
```

then I called class method in ServerManager for post request which returns a int.

```
int i = [serverManager postOperation:params];
```

The variable `"i"` is not assigned and next statement is called. Then server gives back the response after few seconds.
How can I get a synchronised way here for assign the server response to local?
In the class method, I've called:

```
 [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST:url parameters:params 
    success^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    ....;
    }failure^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    ....;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's happening here is `AFNetworking` is sending out the server `POST` request on another thread, and then moving onto execute the line after `int i = [serverManager postOperation:params];` You actually don't want to block/stop all behavior (ie: make it synchronous) until the server returns its response and assigns it to `int i`, because that would result in an unresponsive app, and frustrating experience for the user, so the fact that execution moves onto the next line is desirable. You want to allow `AFNetworking` to send out its request on another thread, while your app still remains responsive to user interactions.

A clean way to do this is to send a completion block into that method to be called in the `success` block of `AFNetworking`. Wrap your call to `[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST:url parameters:params....` inside a method, and call that.

For example:

```
- (void)registerUserWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *results))completion
{
  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST:url parameters:params success^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSArray *results = [responseObject valueForKey:@"results"];
    if(completion){
      completion(results);
    }
    } failure^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
      if(completion){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        completion(nil); // send nil to indicate the call has failed for some reason.
      }
   }];
 }
```

Then call that method like so:

```
[self registerUserWithCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {
   if (results.count > 0) {
   // API call was successful. Do something with the results.
   NSNumber *i = [results objectAtIndex:0];
   // Do something with that variable.
   }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helps.